# Explicit formula for EWMA(n) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, smoothing, moving-average, exponential

I have the following `pandas.core.series.Series`:
`x=pd.Series([17.39, 8.70, 2.90, 1.45, 1.45])` for `t=0,1,2,3,4`.
When I try `x.ewm(span=2).mean()` I get the following results:

`17.39, 10.87, 5.35, 2.71, 1.86`

My understanding is that `.ewm.mean()` uses the following explicit formula:

`y[t] = (1 - alpha) * y[t-1] + alpha * x[t],  where alpha = 2/(span+1)`

`y[0] = x[0]`

Using the above formula:

`EMWA[0] = x[0] = 17.39`

`EMWA[1] = (1-(2/(2+1)))*17.39 + (2/(2+1))*8.7 = 11.59` which is different to `10.87`.

`EMWA[2] = (1-(2/(2+1)))*10.87 + (2/(2+1))*2.9 = 5.55` which is different to `5.35`.

`EMWA[3] = (1-(2/(2+1)))*5.35 + (2/(2+1))*1.45 = 2.75` which is different to `2.71`. etc..

Could you please help me understand where these differences coming from? What I am missing or doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: For those jumping from R to Python (like me), in the following link you will find the difference between `TTR::EMA(x,n=2)` which simply computes the first non-missing value as the arithmetic mean of the first `n` variables and then recursively use `y[t] = (1 - alpha) * y[t-1] + alpha * x[t]` (for t>n), and the way `x.ewm(span=2, adjust = False).mean()` uses the `y[0]=x[0]` and then recursively `y[t] = (1 - alpha) * y[t-1] + alpha * x[t]` (for t>=1). 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557697/using-ttr-package-to-calculate-exponential-moving-average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula that you're using is correct for `x.ewm(span=2, adjust = False).mean()`. Here is some simple code that correctly replicates the behavior under the default `adjust = True` setting.

```
span = 2
alpha = 2/(span + 1)

num = 0
den = 0
for b in x:
    num = (1 - alpha)*num + b
    den = 1 + (1 - alpha)*den
    print(num/den)
```

For more, see the [documentation for ewm](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) and look at the description for the `adjust` parameter.

---

The documentation gives you a summation formula for the `adjust = True` version for the EW function. If you want a comparable formula for the `adjust = False` version, it turns out that EMWA[n] is given by the result of

```
result = (1-alpha)**n * x[0] + alpha * sum((1-alpha)**(n-k) for k in range(1,t+1))
```

That is,

```
                      n                      
                    ____                     
                    ╲                        
       n             ╲           (n - k)     
(1 - α)  ⋅ x  + α ⋅  ╱    (1 - α)        ⋅ x 
            0       ╱                       k
                    ‾‾‾‾                     
                    k = 1
```